# How to give equal widths for ion buttons

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am very new for Ionic apps development i am learning now ionic UI components,How can we fit buttons with equal widths my code is below can some help me please

### code:

```
<ion-content padding>
<div>
  <button outline ion-button color="secondary" (click)="save()">Save</button> 
  <button outline ion-button color="secondary" (click)="Edit()">Edit</button>
  <button outline ion-button color="secondary"(click)="Update()">Update</button>
<div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you need them in one line or below each other?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ion-grid for that. If you don't provide specific width of column then it will take width according to the number of elements in the row. Here's what you are looking for.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
           <button outline ion-button color="secondary" (click)="save()">Save</button> 
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
           <button outline ion-button color="secondary" (click)="Edit()">Edit</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
           <button outline ion-button color="secondary"(click)="Update()">Update</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

You can find more information here. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content padding>
<div>
  <button outline style="width:100px" ion-button color="secondary" (click)="save()">Save</button> 
  <button outline style="width:100px" ion-button color="secondary" (click)="Edit()">Edit</button>
  <button outline style="width:100px" ion-button color="secondary"(click)="Update()">Update</button>
<div>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: no this is not working i want to show all buttons horizontally with equal widths